# Update Kafka 1 to Kafka 2

Tags: apache-kafka

We are running an Apache Kafka 1.1.0 cluster with 5 brokers.

Since the machines are managed via Ansible, for us, the easiest way to update, would be rebuild the brokers one by one with the new version.

The main question is, can some brokers with 1.1.0 and some brokers with 2.3.0 coexist in the same cluster at the same time?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/upgrade-guide provides valuable information about this

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not the best practise, you can have brokers with different version in the same cluster. You'd have to configure `inter.broker.protocol.version` accordingly:

> Specify which version of the inter-broker protocol will be used. This
>   is typically bumped after all brokers were upgraded to a new version.
>   Example of some valid values are: 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.1.1, 0.8.2,
>   0.8.2.0, 0.8.2.1, 0.9.0.0, 0.9.0.1 Check ApiVersion for the full list.

However, if the older and latest versions have a huge gap in-between, you might end up with compatibility (or other) issues.

["Upgrading from previous versions"](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade) section in Kafka docs, should shed some more light.